# Relation between probability density and transmission probability of a wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, probability

Problems I did on current densities in elementary quantum mecanics course gives the answer contains transmission coeffecients, I am wondering is there any relation among them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Probability current is defined as 
$$J(x,t)=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\bigg(\Psi\frac{\partial \Psi^*}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x}\Psi^*\bigg)$$

If the scattering matrix is defined as

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
S_{11}&S_{12}\\
S_{21}&S_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The transmission coefficient $T$ is given by $(S_{21})^2$, this is only true in the case where the velocity of the particle remains same after scattering,

If its not then the transmission coefficient $T$ is given by

$$T=\frac{J_a}{J_b}$$

where $J_a$ and $J_b$ represents the probability current after and before scattering respectively.